# Dreamweaver-Background image resizing

Tags: html, css

I am making a website.But I have a problem.My background image comes up bigger than the screen every time I preview it.

HTML:

```
<div class="image">
     <img src="images/background.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.image { 
   position: absolute;
   margin-left: -50px; 
   margin-top: -25px;  
 }
```

My image's size is 1920x1200

EDIT:
I did it by this code:

```
html { 
  background: url(images/background.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Could it not be the div itself that floats outside the screen? Otherwise, just use `background-size:100%;` on `.image`.

Comment: Do you mean the background is bigger than the div.image container? Can you show an example? Because what you just may need to define is background-size: 100% auto;

Comment: what do you want the solution to be?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend putting the background image in through the CSS and then using `background-size: cover;` as this will scale it with the browser window.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**CSS**

```
.image { 
   background-image:url(images/background.jpg);
   background-size:100%;
   position: absolute;
   margin-left: -50px; 
   margin-top: -25px;  
   width:Xpx; /* change X to what you want */
   height:Ypx;  /* change Y to what you want */
 }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="image">
</div>
```

It's important however that you with this method add `height` and `width` properties to *.image*, so that the div won't have 0x0 in dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what you are trying to do here but you are adding the styles to the div not the image.

```
.image img{ position: absolute; margin-left: -50px; margin-top: -25px; }
```

Would be the markup to affect the image inside a div.

Anyway use body background-image instead. And there are some js files for fitting images to any size display.

Good luck with your site!